Error when I try to open Crystal Report files in Windows 10
Thanks in advance for the help.
First of all I want to give you a bit of context.  I have to start by saying that I have no experience with Crystal Report or any other program of its kind. If I got into working with this program at all, it is out of pure necessity.
For work reasons, I had to migrate a ticketing application that worked with Crystal Report (I don't know which version) on Windows XP to a Windows 10 computer.
Obviously, when doing the migration, I have encountered a lot of compatibility problems when I wanted to open the application. Most of them, luckily, I have managed to solve them somehow (sometimes without knowing how). However, one thing I still can't figure out is opening the .rpt files on the new computer.
I have installed both Crystal Report 2020 and Crystal Report Viewer 2016, but neither will let me. With the first one, when I try to open the file the program closes completely. While with the second one, I get the message that the file was saved in a version of Crystal Reports prior to version 9 and cannot be viewed.
I don't know if there is a solution to this as I don't have access to the old computer with Windows XP. This one broke down and that is why I have been trying to migrate everything to a new computer.
I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much.

CR went through some significant changes between version 8.5 and XI.  You may be able to open them and update them using CR XI if you find a copy of this version.  Then once the report is converted for version XI, you may be able to open it the 2016 or 2020 version to update the report the rest of the way.  But I have no way to guarantee that is possible or will work as expected.  They may be another version of CR needed in between 8.5 and 2020 beyond just XI as well.  The best way to learn more about the upgrade path would be to ask SAP directly though.
